# Is there any way to generate ID combined with alphabets in java?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I have created a students registration project and I need to give registration number on my own for those who are registering in my website. My Registration Id should be ABC0000001 so on. I tried this following code to generate reg no.

```
 for(int i=0000001;i<3;i++){

  System.out.println("ABC"+i);

}
```

But I got output as 
    ABC1
    ABC2
    ABC3. This is not needed. Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers do not have significant leading zeros. (Never mind that the code actually uses an *octal* number literal in Java.)

See [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and the [Format Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). In particular, '0' *flag*, *width* modifier, and the 'd' (decimal integer) *conversion* are useful here.

```
for(int i=1; i<3; i++){
  // % - start of format
  // 0 - 0-pad the result
  // 7 - set result width to 7 characters wide
  // d - display as decimal integer
  String id = String.format("ABC%07d", i);
  System.out.println(id);
}
```

Comment: +1 for Nice Job done! Is it applicable for all? i.e. long, float etc ?

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena The `d` integral conversion "may be applied to Java integral types: byte, Byte, short, Short, int and Integer, long, Long, and BigInteger" (see the Conversions section in the Format Syntax, linked above). To display a float, either use one of the floating-point conversions like `f` or convert it to an integral type before passing it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
for(int i=1;i<3;i++){

  System.out.println("ABC00000"+i);

}
```