# Printing integers starting with 0's - java

Tags: java, variables, integer

The issue is that I do not understand how to make two 0's appear before the 7, after the print. the print keeps coming up with just the 7 after the + bond is used in the print line.

int bond = 007;
System.out.println("insert what ever you want " + bond);
insert what ever you want 7

What i want it so say is

insert what ever you want 007

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720130/is-there-any-way-to-generate-id-combined-with-alphabets-in-java/21720170#21720170

Comment: Please make sure to phrase a proper question. Also, please format your code for best readability. This will greatly improve your chances of getting a good answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", Bond));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is an `int`, it will trim the `0` from the start of the number. This is because `007` is numerically equal to `7`. Use a `String` instead:

```
String bond = "007";

System.out.println("Insert whatever you want " + bond);
```

Alternatively, if you *have to* use an `int`, then you can use the `format` method as so:

```
System.out.println("Insert whatever you want" + String.format("%02d", bond));
```

***Edit***

Excellent point made in the comments. `007` will be interpreted as an `octal` number, which means `007` will actually be interpreted as `042`. Agent 042 is the jealous spy, who always tries to pull off what `007` can, but never quite succeeds. We don't want him taking any of `007`'s glory.

Comment: (In addition, Java actually treats a numeric integer literal starting with a zero as octal. Agent 042 - `042 != 42` - will have a nasty surprise when he tries to cash a paycheck!)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [System.out.printf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like so,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%03d - %s, %s.\n", 7, "Bond", "James Bond");
}
```

Outputs,

```
007 - Bond, James Bond.
```